# standard convention for naming Rails local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, naming

So this is a bit of an opinionated question but somebody was looking at my Rails code (specifically model code) and was taking umbrage with how I name local variables.

To be honest, due to way Ruby works, I intentionally don't name something that could look like an attribute and will often name them something like id_tmp since id could easily be an attribute. He felt that this was a really boneheadish thing to do - who's right?

like in a User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def say_something
    # my verion which I prefer but not super emphatically
    location_ids_tmp=Location.getAssociatedIds
    # his version which he prefers greatly but the more I think about it, the less I like
    location_ids=Location.getAssociatedIds
```

I wasn't offended but it was a typical programmer argument where I can't get it out of my head.

Who is right? Or should this be a context derived argument?

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition that you don't want to name a variable after a keyword like `class`, `id`, etc.  is correct. However, you don't need to do that if the variable name includes something like `location_`. `location_ids` is more idiomatic, I would say. But no variable name will clash with a reserved keyword if you have something prepended or appended.

Comment: thx for answer. if a user has_many :locations, then there IS a location_ids attribute on User - I think if you see location_ids in a model, I wonder whether there is that association. Just seems like it's more explicit to say location_ids_tmp or something. In the context of a local variable you wouldn't need self hence the confusion. I know this is primarily a stylistic convention but ...